# Why is the output of date format conversion and timestamp conversion different?

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

The timestamp and date conversion codes below echo different outputs. I also set the default time zone but no joy. Please can someone tell me what's wrong because I'm noticing this for the first time? I also tried it on a live server and it's the same thing.

```php
echo date("d F, Y", 1578079200).'<br/>'; //03 January, 2020
echo strtotime("3 January, 2020").'<br/>'; //1609705200
echo date("d F, Y", 1609705200).'<br/>'; //03 January, 2021
```

Thank you very much

Comment: If you remove the comma, what is the outcome? 2021 is the current year on your computers clock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strtotime("3 January, 2020")
```

gives you the date of 3 January *this* year (spoiler: at 20:20 hours, minutes).

```
strtotime("3 January 2020")
```

gives you the date of 3 January of *2020* year (spoiler: at 00:00 hours, minutes).

---

> Why is the output of date format conversion and timestamp conversion different?

Because that are different formats. Each different format converts differently.

If you precisely know about the date format and you want to parse a date, please see [DateTime::parseFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```php
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F, Y', '3 January, 2020');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'), "\n";
echo $date->getTimestamp(), "\n";
```

```
2020-01-03
1578007000
```